# Is it possible to constantly long-poll from a Django server?

Tags: django, blocking, long-polling

I have a Django server and I'd like to add a component to read from a Redis stream. This will work by putting a blocking read call in an infinite loop. When the thread unblocks, it will write some data to the database.

Is there a recommended approach to doing this? Should this be done outside of the main server in a worker? Is it possible to maybe do this in another thread?

Also, where should this code reside in the project?

Comment: Yes, you should do this in a seperate process/worker. Many solutions for this, the simplest yet least complete is just to create a script with a `while True` loop in it and run that

Comment: What is your Redis stream like? I'm also trying to implement a Redis stream that sends notif when a cache expires, so I use celery to execute code. If anything, you should put an initial function in apps.py, maybe using asyncio, to run your stream.

Comment: @yoomama I was thinking about doing this is well, but don't have much experience with it. We're using the redis stream to get updates from a legacy system. I'll try looking into running the loop in another thread with asyncio.

Comment: What is populating the stream? If you use celery you could possibly change the stream to a celery task queue

Comment: @IainShelvington We're not using celery for this project, although we can add it if that's the best solution. I'm a little uneasy about having two queues though.

Comment: @Hassan I'm using the following: https://tech.webinterpret.com/redis-notifications-python/ Redis keyspace notifications. This is the issue with the following it tho: in the ex, the message is in a while True loop. That's why I use celery using its tasks (it's been awhile for me so I forgot why I initially used celery, but Iain got it). The point is to not use a stream but that notifications Pub/Sub.